# how to use HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT in swift file

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

I trying to use HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT in my swift file. In objective C it is working.
I have tried by importing

```
#import <mach/host_info.h>
```

using bridging header but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<mach/host_info.h>` defines `HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT` as

```
#define HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT ((mach_msg_type_number_t) \
            (sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t)/sizeof(integer_t)))
```

and “non-trivial” macro definitions are not imported into Swift.
Therefore you have to define it yourself:

```
let HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT = MemoryLayout<vm_statistics_data_t>.stride/MemoryLayout<integer_t>.stride
```

An alternative is to add

```
#import <mach/host_info.h>

static const mach_msg_type_number_t HostVMInfoCount = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
```

to the bridging header file and then use `HostVMInfoCount` in
the Swift code.